# Filter IP ranges in Logic Apps ARM templates

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps, access-control, azure-rm-template

How can I add "Only other logic apps" filter on Json instead of IP ranges for Restrict inbound IP ranges in Azure Resource Manager template?

I saw in the documentation how to add it from the Azure portal setting "Only other logic apps" in the Allowed inbound IP addresses, but I need to add it from the ARM template for automate the deployment.

I found only the IP ranges option:

```
"accessControl": {
           "triggers": {
              "allowedCallerIpAddresses": [
                 {
                    "addressRange": "192.168.12.0/23"
                 }
              ]
           },
           "actions": {
              "allowedCallerIpAddresses": []
           }
        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set the `allowedCallerIpAddresses` array to empty for the option to allow "Only other logic apps".

e.g.

```
    "accessControl": {
      "triggers": {
        "allowedCallerIpAddresses": []
      },
      "actions": {
        "allowedCallerIpAddresses": []
      }
    },
```

At the time I learned about this, I used the Azure Resource Explorer to view the JSON. Seems like exporting from the Portal doesn't show the setting and I couldn't find any documentation.
https://resources.azure.com/